# Confusion about function declaration

Tags: javascript, function

If I assign a named function to a variable, why I can't access to the named function:

```
var a = function b() {
    console.log("Hello World");
}
a() // hello world;
b() // b is not defined
b  // b is not defined
```

and at this time, I can not delete the `a` variable, but I can delete `b`, when I delete the `b`, the `a`'s function can still there

```
delete a //false
delete b //true
a()  //Hello World
```

the `b` function isn't just referenced by the `a`, not copy, so why the `a` function is still there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a **named function expression** (not a function declaration!), the name of the function is only accessible form inside the function.

From the [specification](http://es5.github.io/#x13) ("Identifier" refers to the name of function, i.e. `function Identifier() {}`):

> The Identifier in a *FunctionExpression* can be referenced from inside the *FunctionExpression*'s *FunctionBody* to allow the function to call itself recursively. However, unlike in a *FunctionDeclaration*, the Identifier in a *FunctionExpression* cannot be referenced from and does not affect the scope enclosing the *FunctionExpression*.

---

> but I can delete `b`

No, you can't. When you pass anything that is not a reference to `delete` or the reference cannot be resolved, [it will return `true`](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.1).

---

This is a great article about all the function definition stuff: http://kangax.github.io/nfe/.