# function property not initialized in function body when invoked from definition

Tags: javascript

In the following, I try invoking the function f2 directly with the definition, and also separately, and it is invoked in both cases.  However, only when invoking it separately is `f2.str` initialized, and not when it is invoked directly with the definition.  Anyone have an explanation?

```
(function f2() {

    alert("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    f2.str = "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE";

}());

//f2();
```

Comment: function f() {
         
        alert(f2.str);

    };

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/16232706/218196

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a function expression, the function name is scoped to that function, so it is not defined outside of it except in buggy versions of IE. Read more about the difference between the different ways to define a function in Javascript [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression):

> There is a distinction between the function name and the variable the function is assigned to:
>
> - The function name cannot be changed, while the variable the function
>     is assigned to can be reassigned.
> - The function name can be used only
>     within the function's body. Attempting to use it outside the
>     function's body results in an error (or undefined if the function
>     name was previously declared via a var statement). For example:
>
>   var y  = function x(){};
>     alert(x); // throws an error
>
>   The function name also appears when the function is serialized via Function's toString
>     method.
>
>   On the other hand, the variable the function is assigned to is
>     limited only by its scope, which is guaranteed to include the scope
>     where the function is declared in.
> - As the 4th example shows, the function name can be different from the
>     variable the function is assigned to. They have no relation to each
>     other.

Example:

```
(function f2() {

    // f2 is defined here

    alert("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    f2.str = "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE";

    // f2.str is defined here

}());

// In buggy versions of IE f2 and f2.str are still defined. 
// In all other browsers they are correctly not defined.
```

If you want to use a function expression and you want `f2` to exist outside it's own scope, then you can do either:

```
var f2 = function() {

    alert("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    f2.str = "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE";

};

f2();
```

Or:

```
var f2; // Declare f2 in this scope
(f2 = function() {

    alert("XXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    f2.str = "EEEEEEEEEEEEEE";

})(); // <-- Note that the parenthesis have been necessarily reordered
```

Comment: That doesn't answer why it works when just calling f2().  I'm running Chrome and FF, btw.

Comment: @Mark try to call `f2()` from your example you will get `ReferenceError`

Comment: @Mark: If you omit the `(...());` from the definition, you have a function **declaration** which creates a symbol for the function in the current scope. If you have `(...());`, then the definition is evaluated as function **expression** and the name of a function expression is always local to the function itself.

Comment: @mark It doesn't work when you just call `f2` unless you defined `f2` using a [function statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) rather than an expression.

Comment: Well,  the fact that you can refer to f2 by name, within f2, means that the name exists at that point.  And you say that even when finally invoking it, f2 still doesn't exist yet.  I guess its how JS is doing it, but seems like a wrongheaded feature.

Comment: @Mark: The name exist, but only *inside* the function. You cannot access it from outside. Just like a local variable.

Comment: OK, Felix King's comment regarding a function expression seems on the money possibly.  Didn't know that parens created a completely different animal.  I would probably credit that as the answer I think.

Comment: @Mark I added a link and a quote from that link to my answer.